# Copy part of XML content in a separate folder using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to copy part of an XML that contains a lot of data. I am trying with something like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder   
import jxl.*   
import jxl.write.*   

 // read the file from path
def file = new File('Path.xml')
// for example read line by line
def myTestCase = context.testCase 
propTestStep = myTestCase.getTestStepByName("Data")    

def data= file.filterLine { line ->
    line.contains('<V1>Value</V1><V2>Value</V2>')
}

propTestStep.setPropertyValue("Value Present", data)
```

but I have problem with writing the content on the property value that I gave ... any idea how I can define that save the value?

In general I am trying to give as a regular expression the xml tags as they should be populated in the request and get only this value ... perhaps I need to use totally different method, but please share this with me if I wrong :)

Edit: The error message that I am getting when I run the code is: **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlPropertiesTestStep.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods$4) values: [Value Present, ] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)**, hope that helps.

Comment: please edit your question and specify what kind of problem you have. the error message, stacktrace, etc.

Comment: Updated it, hope that will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method [File.filterLine()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#filterLine(groovy.lang.Closure))
returns Writable

and the method [WsdlPropertiesTestStep.setPropertyValue(name,value)](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlPropertiesTestStep.html#setPropertyValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
expects string as a value parameter

you just need to convert `data` to string

```groovy
propTestStep.setPropertyValue( "Value Present", data.toString() )
```

Comment: Great! :) The code works now perfectly. 

I just have a problem with the definition of the tags ... its seems that if I give multiple tags the code won't recognize them as a whole and I receive blank result in the property. Any chance to know how I can define it so that it will take multiple lines in a row?